# Jquery - Table row taking two clicks to remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code:

```
<a id="request_'.$row['REQUEST_ID'].'" href="javascript:void(0)" data-requestid="'.$row['REQUEST_ID'].'" onClick="confirmAssistanceRequestDelete(this)">Delete</a>




function deleteAssistanceRequest(id){

if(id > 0){
    $.post("ajax_delete_assistance_request.php", { request_id : id })
        .done( function(response){
        if(response == 0){
            alert("Failed To Delete");
            return false;
        }
        //Delete row

        $('#row'+id).remove();

    });
} else {
alert("Failed.");
}
}



function confirmAssistanceRequestDelete(elem){
var id = $(elem).data('requestid');
$.fancybox(
    '<p>Delete Request: Are You Sure?</p><br/>'+
    '<div class="confirmButtonHolder"><input class="buttonActionSmall" type="button" onClick="deleteAssistanceRequest('+id+')" value="Delete" />'+
    '<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancleDelete" class="buttonActionSmall" /></div>',
    {
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : true,
        'hideOnContentClick' : true,
        'autoDimensions' : false,
        'width' : 300,
        'height' : 120,
        'padding' : 15,
        'closeBtn' : true
    }
);  
}
```

What happens is the user clicks the button, confirms the delete, then the ajax call removes the records from the database. After the deletion completes, the table row is removed.

What I need help with is that for some reason I have to click the delete button twice to get the table row to remove.

Ex: Click delete, confirm it, nothing.
    Click delete, confirm it, row removes.

I've tried using the console to be sure the code is executing all the way through and it seems to be. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: from the sounds of it, what would console from your php file (the response)

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but if you are asking what the console would log.. it was dependent on what I was testing for. I tried using a counter to make sure it wasn't reloading something. I used the console to display the id to make sure it was processing correctly. I did some extra testing pulling additional data from the object to be sure it was the correct object being initialized. All responses came back as expected

Comment: in the $.post you have a response = 0 but i can't see anything wrong in your js, it looks valid and the alert isn't happening but i don't see your html nor your php, by the fact that you said its eventually removing, it seems like thats valid so the only left is your php, it might be your id variable is not being referenced right so you could possibly console.log that *shrug* without some way to actually run it, i can only validate

Comment: I tried taking the php out of the question completely and just passing it as true (regardless of what happened on back end in the DB). I did a console.log of the ID to be sure that it was being passed correctly and it is. It's just strange because if you click it twice (running the same function) it removes on the second go around =\

Comment: if you're sure it calls it on the first time? Be assured its not because you're writing your js wrong.... last suggestion since i see you using jQuery: run a callback function after fancybox instantiates, use jQuery to attach a click handler, call e.preventDefault() after and then do the last of the functionality. also you can also hook into a success function and a failure function (just don't forget to remove said click handler if fancybox closes), its not perfect but it'll get what you need done, done. I  have some doubts about the onClick is all

Comment: if you're not using fancybox anywhere else, i could also suggest you to use bootbox (for a bootstrap stylish confirmation box). something is holding onto your click event or something somewhere is being a little greedy

Comment: I'll look into it. Fancybox is used everywhere across the site so I can't change it. I'll get back to you.